# SELECT next smallest available number that does not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table column that stores decimal numbers, for example:

```
number  status     paid_how
1.54    completed  paypal
1.54    not paid   paypal
1.53    not paid   paypal
1.51    not paid   paypal
```

The number column must remain unique for all statuses that do not equal "completed". So if try to insert another number that is 1.54 with a status of "not paid", I need to change the number downwards to an unique value. In the example above it couldnt insert 1.54, 1.53 but 1.52 should be accepted.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out a select query that can determine the next lowest number while the status !="completed".

Comment: You can find minimum of number whose status is not equal to "completed"? Then you could subtract -0.01?

Comment: What is the data-type of the `number` column? If it's a floating-point value then the "next smallest" could be 1.5299999999, for example.

Comment: Do you want to do this in Insert query or in update ?

Comment: sorry Dai I didn't give enough detail. The number column is stored as decimal 3,2.

Comment: Alpesh, well I wanted to run a select query first to find the next available number in PHP and then insert

Comment: That requires a loop for which you'd write a recursive query in SQL. MySQL, however, doesn't support recursive queries as yet. Your best bet may be to `select number from mytable where status = 'not paid' and number <= 1.54`. Then in PHP write a loop starting with 1.54 going down until you find a number that is not among the retrieved numbers. I don't know, whether the same could be done with a stored procedure in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(my_number)
from my_table
where status != 'completed'
```

if you want the next number you should use - then something like:

```
select min(my_number)-.01
into my_next_number
from my_table
where status != 'completed'
```